# Redirect after login not working for me

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am making a page in which once the login is authenticated, it should redirect to a landing page. I have used a login wizard. On click of any links in the navigation bar (if not logged on), it redirects to a separate sign up page. what is happening is, as soon as i login, it takes me directly to the sign up page instead of the landing page. I am including codes for login page and web.config. BTW, I am using Bootstrap.

**Login Page:**

```
public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string UserLogins = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB1"].ConnectionString.ToString();

    public static object ConfigurationManager { get; private set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
        Boolean blnresult;
        blnresult = false;

        blnresult = Authentication(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password);
        if (blnresult == true)
        {
            e.Authenticated = true;
            Response.Redirect("LandingPage.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            e.Authenticated = false;
        }
    }

    protected static Boolean Authentication(string usernames, string passwords)
    {
        string sqlcmd;
        sqlcmd = "SELECT UName, Pwd from  [SignupDB] where UName = '" + usernames + "' and Pwd = '" + passwords + "'";
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|/DB1.mdb;Persist Security Info=True;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=mypassword");
        con.Close();
        con.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlcmd, con);
        OleDbDataReader reader;
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.Read())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

**web.config:**

```
<add name="SignupDB" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=&quot;C:\Users\admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\mysite\App_Data\DB1.mdb&quot;;Persist Security Info=True;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=mypassword" providerName="System.Data.OleDb"/>
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="RegPage.aspx" name="login" protection="Validation" defaultUrl="LandingPage.aspx" cookieless="UseCookies" timeout="200" enableCrossAppRedirects="true"/>
</authentication>
<authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: try to debug in your page load event at "Landing page" to ensure that user is logged in.

Comment: [Correct use of Redirect](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2009/06/25/correct-use-of-system-web-httpresponse-redirect.aspx)

Comment: Add code of LandingPage's `page_load`

Comment: Are you able to debug and your debug is going in to this condition -> if(blnresult==true)    {  ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the Redirect is not your problem. The problem is you are not logging with Forms Authentication so when you redirect to any protected page by Forms Authentication, it will redirect you back to login page. Take a look in this method, to initialize Forms Authentication.

```
private void Authenticate(string login)
{
  FormsAuthentication.Initialize();

  var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
                                             login,
                                             DateTime.Now,
                                             DateTime.Now.AddHours(3), // time of user's session .. add more if you need
                                             false,
                                             null);

  var encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

  if (!FormsAuthentication.CookiesSupported)
  {
      FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(encryptedTicket, false);
  }
  else
  {
      HttpCookie authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);

      authCookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;

      System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
  }  
}
```

You could call it when your login succeed, for sample:

```
protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    Boolean blnresult;
    blnresult = false;

    blnresult = Authentication(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password);
    if(blnresult)
    {
        e.Authenticated = true;

        // authenticate using Forms Authentication
        Authenticate(Login1.UserName);

        Response.Redirect("LandingPage.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        e.Authenticated = false;
    }
}
```

I also did some improvements on your database access to make sure you are closing the database connection:

```
protected static bool Authentication(string usernames, string passwords)
{
    string sqlcmd = "SELECT UName, Pwd from  [SignupDB] where UName = '" + usernames + "' and Pwd = '" + passwords + "'";

    using(OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|/DB1.mdb;Persist Security Info=True;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=mypassword"))
    {
      con.Open();
      OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlcmd, con);
      using(OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
      {
        if (reader.Read())
            return true;
        else
            return false;

      }
    }    
}
```